# Javascript / jQuery / AJAX - Request string from website

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, api, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to create a function, using an API, to get the definition in french of a word.

I'm using this API:

```
"http://www.igrec.ca/project-files/wikparser/wikparser.php?word="
 + word + 
"&query=def&count=1&lang=fr"
```

This url returns one definition in plain text of the word entered.
e.g: http://www.igrec.ca/project-files/wikparser/wikparser.php?word=manger&query=def&count=1&lang=fr

How does one manage to get this text? I looked at similar questions, some mention Ajax / xmlHttpRequest but I'm pretty lost.

Thanks

P.S: I don't mind using jQuery or some other technics as long as I understand what I'm doing.

Comment: You're looking for the documentation.  But beware the same-origin policy.

Comment: *"Ajax or xmlHttpRequest"* one and the same

Comment: @SLaks Not really... I don't know what to look at, first of all before finding out how. Need advices on what to use for example...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The basic jQuery AJAX call can be done like this ... (using your data).

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://www.igrec.ca/project-files/wikparser/wikparser.php",
  dataType: "text",
  data: {
    word: word,
    query: "def",
    count: 1,
    lang: "fr",
  },
  success: function(data) {
    // Do something
  }
});
```

Basically, you are performing a GET, at the URL.

The data type you expect back is text.

The data gets "transformed" into the url format from your question, then there is a success function to handle the data received.

Comment: Thanks, I shall start from here then.

Comment: Glad I could help ... this is one of those staples I use almost daily.  There are variations of this, but it should give you a good start.

Comment: How come this AJAX request doesn't return any data?

To test it I've done: 
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);

    },

    error: function(){
     console.log(w);
     console.log("error");
    }

And I never get success and always error

Comment: What error are you getting ... use `console.log(w)` in the error function.